# 404 error for socket.io.js Using tornadoio and socketio

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, tornado

Socketio website is using node.js as the back end for socket emulation,I am  trying to use Tornadoio as  the backend.but  it  is note  delevering the file socket.io.js

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't need that file in order to use websockets.

you can use

```
ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8888/ws');
ws.onopen = function (str) {
    console.log("Someone sent: ", str);
};
```

I had the same doubt when I switch from node.js to Tornado.

Hope it helps